# Int 13h Call Placing Data Before Buffer

Tags: assembly, buffer, bootloader

I am developing a small OS bootloader. I am using the int 0x13 function to read the first sector of a hard drive. The problem is that if I pass it in the address 0x7e00 as the buffer, I get the data starting at 0x7d71.

For testing purposes, the hard drive is 2 KB filled with the letter 'A'. I am using Qemu to test my bootloader.

Here is a piece of my code:

```
mov ax, 0x7e00    ; Address to place data.
shr ax, 4         ; Shift right for es index instead of bx
mov es, ax        ; Put buffer address into es
xor bx, bx        ; Zero out bx, because it is not needed
mov ah, 0x02      ; Sub function to read disks
mov al, 0x01      ; Read 1 sector
xor ch, ch        ; At cylinder 0
mov cl, 0x01      ; At sector 1
xor dh, dh        ; At head 0
mov dl, 0x80      ; On hard drive 0
int 0x13
```

Later, when I happen to read 0x7d71:

```
mov al, byte [0x7d71]    ; Get the character at 0x7d71
mov ah, 0x0e             ; Sub function to teletype print al
xor bx, bx               ; On page 0
mov cx, 0x00001          ; 1 time
int 0x10
```

I get the letter 'A'. And I can continue going up in addresses, and still get an 'A'.

Am I sending in the buffer to es:bx wrong? Is the bios messed up? (I am using Qemu to emulate, nasm to assembly, and magiciso to produce the iso)

Comment: Just for clarification, are you not getting the desired data `AAAA...` for one sector length at `0x7E00`? What's the value of AX register just after the `INT 0x13` instruction gets executed?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to NOT fill the first sector of that HD with A's and then read in the second sector instead. Could it be your current bootprogram is 0x0171 bytes in length? I guess your bootloader is not physically loaded from that first sector but QEMU did load an entire sector of A's at 0x7C00 and then placed just 0x0171 bytes of programcode at 0x7C00

Comment: My program is located on the first sector of a cd plugged into the machine. I am loading the first sector of a hard drive into 0x7E00. My code should be loaded at 0x7C00, and is padded to be 512 bytes long. I don't know how the machine is writting the 'A's at 0x7D71.

Comment: I do believe that if your program has 0x0171 bytes without the padding that fact could lead to better understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved itself. I had to manually specify the buffer to be at 0x7C90 for the data to be placed at 0x7C00. I cleaned my code up and added more stuff, which solved the problem somehow. Thanks for the help though.